# Get data from the slack app ( text ) and use it in Github Actions

Tags: javascript, github-actions, slack, slack-api

Question : I want to send a message in my slack channel and get that text back from the bot present in the channel using github actions.

Tried: I have used the slack send github action where I have a github action workflow with the following code.

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Post to a Slack channel
      id: slack
      uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.18.0
      with:
        channel-id: 'C032NCAKJPR'
        slack-message: "Does it Work"
      env:
        SLACK_BOT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN }}
```

With this whatever I enter in the slack-message will be sent in the channel by the bot. I am not sure how to proceed with getting the data from the channel and then passing that into this workflow so the bot sends the same text back.

Comment: Hey Yash, can you please clarify this part: I am not sure how to proceed with getting the data from the channel, what data, and from where?

Comment: The data as in a message sent by me in the channel. Like the main goal is to send a message in Slack and using github actions the slack bot sends the same message back to the channel. With the above method it will send the text 'Does it Work', but what I want is to get the text that I put into the channel and then that text is used in slack-message part.

Comment: Ahh got, so basically you want to trigger a GitHub action from Slack, and after the GitHub action is triggered reply back with your original message? Sorry for another question, but I'm trying to understand in order to help :)

Comment: Yepp thats exactly it, user sends message in slack, github action takes place, bot sends back the same message. I got it working with node using the web api and event api but I am able to figure it out using Github Actions. Its no worries, I'm glad you are helping me :)